# Removing pairs of elements in an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, element

I know similar questions have been asked before, but they typically remove all of the specified element from an Arraylist.

What I need to do, is remove pairs of values from my ArrayList (if a number occurs 3 times, it will remove 2 copies of that element and leave 1 of them). More generally, if a number occurs an odd number of times leave 1, if a number occurs an even number of times remove them all. Thus, if my Arraylist was something like this

[5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1],

the output would be

[5, 4, 3]

Since the number "2" appears twice, it is complete removed. Same with the number "1". But since the number "3" appears three times, it leaves one of them in the ArrayList, because I only want to remove the numbers in pairs.

I don't care at all about the ordering, as I'm going to reorder it anyways.

Does anyone have any suggestions on doing this? I think I could use a for loop that compares each value over and over, but it seems inefficient, so I was curious if there would be a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: *I don't care at all about the ordering* then use `Set` that doesn't allow duplicate values.

Comment: Please clarify your question .. I don't understand how 2 or 1 would not be in our output set

Comment: Not clear to me as well.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Sorry about that, I've made a few edits trying to clarify how it works. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @user3218114: if he caredabout the order, he could still use a LinkedHashSet.

Comment: @JBNizet that's is also an `Set`. I used `Set` in broad way.

Comment: @user3218114 Doesn't a set leave one value in it though if that number appears just twice? If so, then that won't work for what I need it for. Number have to be removed in pairs.

Comment: @user3218114: your comment looked to me like a Set can only be used because the OP doesn't care about the ordering.

Comment: @JBNizet I mentioned for duplicate values as well.

Comment: What happens if there are four values in the original array? Remove two, or remove all (both pairs)?

Comment: @Mshnik Remove two pairs, leaving you with no more of that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowed to sort the arraylist, this becomes pretty simple.

```
public void removePairedElements(ArrayList<Integer> a){

    Collections.sort(a); //Sort a

    int i = 0;
    while(i < a.size() - 1){
      //Check if i and i+1 are the same element. If so, remove both
      if(a.get(i).equals(a.get(i+1))){
        //Remove i twice - effectively removes i and i+1
        a.remove(i);
        a.remove(i);

        //Move i *back* one index, which is equivalent to 
        //moving forward one because we just removed two elements.
        //Prevent i from becoming negative though.
        i = Math.max(0, (i - 1));
      }
      else{
        i++;
      }
    }
}
```

O(n log n) time and O(1) space. Probably the cleanest answer. If you aren't allowed to change the ordering of the arraylist you'd have to do something else, but otherwise this should work.

Comment: Hmmm, this concept seems to be like a good idea. It's not producing the correct output, but I think I may try to modify it and see if I can figure out whats wrong.

Comment: I got the bug, see edit - removing i+1 after removing i is effectively removing i+2, which isn't what we want.

Comment: Ah, of course, because everything gets shifted over. This works flawlessly (as far as I've tested it) and looks to be the simplest code to me. Thank you so much for the help, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map as a helper.

- iterate over the ArrayList
- Lets say the i'th element of the list contains the number n.
- If map.containsKey(n), map.get(n) is the location in the list of the previous occurrence of n.

  - remove both the i'th element and the map.get(n)'th element from the list.
  - remove the key n from the map.
- Else

  - map.put (n,i)

Implementation note :

Don't use an enhanced for loop to iterate over the list (since it doesn't allow removal of elements). Iterate over the indices of the list. This will allow you to remove the elements by their index (but remember that when you remove the i'th element, the previous i+1 element becomes the new i'th element).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to sort the list.

Then, going backwards, remove ints if you see the same one while keeping track of the total count of current ints.

If you see an even total count, you will NOT remove the last occurrence.
If you see an odd total count, you will remove the last occurence.

```
public void removePairElementsFrom(Arraylist<Integer> myArrayList)
{
    if (myArrayList == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    int arrayLength = myArrayList.size();

    if (arrayLegnth == 1)
    {
        return myArrayList;
    )

    Collections.sort(myArrayList);

    int lastSeenInt = myArrayList.get(arrayLength - 1);
    int lastSeenIntCount = 1;

    for (int i = arrayLength - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (myArrayList[i] == lastSeenInt)
        {
            myArrayList.remove(i+1);
            ++lastSeenIntCount;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((lastSeenIntCount % 2) == 0)
            {
                myArrayList.remove(i+1);
            }

            lastSeenInt = myArrayList.get(i);
            lastSeenIntCount = 1;
        }
    }

    if ((lastSeenIntCount % 2) == 0)
    {
        myArrayList.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: This seems close to what I want, however on the output it's leaving me with a 1 which seems to be the only problem. I'm thinking it could be because 1 is the last number listed in the ArrayList and the counting or something might be wrong somewhere?

Comment: 1 is the first element in the sorted list, so it's not doing the check for it when going backwards.

I added a check at the end to take care of that.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Write a method removeBadPairs that accepts an ArrayList of integers and removes any adjacent pair 
of integers in the list if the left element of the pair is larger than the right element of the pair. Every pair's 
left element is an even-numbered index in the list, and every pair's right element is an odd index in the list. 
For example, suppose a variable called list stores the following element values:

```
[3, 7, 9, 2, 5, 5, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 3, 1]
```

We can think of this list as a sequence of pairs: (3, 7), (9, 2), (5, 5), (8, 5), (6, 3), (4, 7), (3, 1). The pairs (9, 
2), (8, 5), (6, 3), and (3, 1) are "bad" because the left element is larger than the right one, so these pairs 
should be removed. So the call of `removeBadPairs(list);` would change the list to store the following 
element values:

```
[3, 7, 5, 5, 4, 7]
```

If the list has an odd length, the last element is not part of a pair and is also considered "bad;" it should 
therefore be removed by your method. 
If an empty list is passed in, the list should still be empty at the end of the call. You may assume that the 
list passed is not null. You may not use any other arrays, lists, or other data structures to help you solve 
this problem, though you can create as many simple variables as you like.

Comment: Please format your post by using backticks(the key next to 1 on your keyboard) to surround any code like so `\`code\`` and separate your text into paragraphs to make your text more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error if you start from the start of the list using For loop due to an iterator. So I have an alternate way.

```
class RemoveBadPairs {    
    Public Static void main() {
        ArrayList numbersList = new ArrayList();
        numberslist={3,7,9,2,5,5,8,5,6,3,4,7,3,1,7};   
        System.out.println("Original List...");
        for (e in : numbersList) {
            System.out.print("{0},", e);
        }
        if (((numbersList.Count % 2)!= 0)) {
            numbersList.RemoveAt((numbersList.Count - 1));
        }
        for (int i = (numbersList.Count - 1); (i <= 0); i = (i + -2)) {
            if ((numbersList[i] < numbersList[(i - 1)])) {
                numbersList.RemoveRange((i - 1), 2);
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Final List...");
        for (e in : numbersList) {
            System.out.print(","+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

*I hope this will work.*